# Interpolate NA values in a data frame with na.approx

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation

I am trying to remove `NA`s from my data frame by interpolation with `na.approx()` but can't remove all of the `NA`s.

My data frame is a 4096x4096 with 270.15 as flag for non valid value. I need data to be continous in all points to feed a meteorological model. Yesterday I asked, and obtained an answer, on how to replace values in a data frame based in another data frame. But after that I came to `na.approx()` and then decided to replace the 270.15 values with `NA` and try `na.approx()` to interpolate data. But the question is why `na.approx()` does not replace all NAs.

This is what I am doing:

- Read the original hdf file with hdf5load
- Subset the data frame (4094x4096)
- Substitute flag value with NA

  ```
  > sst4[sst4 == 270.15 ] = NA
  ```
- Check first column (or any other)

  ```
  > summary(sst4[,1])

  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's
  271.3   276.4   285.9   285.5   292.3   302.8  1345.0
  ```
- Run na.approx

  ```
  > sst4=na.approx(sst4,na.rm="FALSE")
  ```
- Check first column

  ```
  > summary(sst4[,1]) 
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's
  271.3   276.5   286.3   285.9   292.6   302.8   411.0
  ```

As you can see 411 NA's have not been removed. Why? Do they all correspond to leading/ending column values?

```
head(sst4[,1])
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
tail(sst4[,1])
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Is it needed by na.approx to have valid values before and after NA to interpolate? Do I need to set any other na.approx option?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A small, reproducible example:

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(runif(16, 0, 100), nrow = 4)
missing_values <- sample(16, 7)
m[missing_values] <- NA
m
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 26.55087 20.16819 62.911404 68.70228
[2,] 37.21239       NA  6.178627 38.41037
[3,]       NA       NA        NA       NA
[4,] 90.82078 66.07978        NA       NA

na.approx(m)
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 26.55087 20.16819 62.911404 68.70228
[2,] 37.21239 35.47206  6.178627 38.41037
[3,] 64.01658 50.77592        NA       NA
[4,] 90.82078 66.07978        NA       NA

m[4, 4] <- 50
na.approx(m)
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 26.55087 20.16819 62.911404 68.70228
[2,] 37.21239 35.47206  6.178627 38.41037
[3,] 64.01658 50.77592        NA 44.20519
[4,] 90.82078 66.07978        NA 50.00000
```

Yup, looks like you do need the start/end values of columns to be known or the interpolation doesn't work. Can you guess values for your boundaries?

ANOTHER EDIT: So by default, you need the start and end values of columns to be known.  However it is possible to get `na.approx` to always fill in the blanks by passing `rule = 2`.  See Felix's answer.  You can also use `na.fill` to provide a default value, as per Gabor's comment.  Finally, you can interpolate boundary conditions in two directions (see below) or guess boundary conditions.

---

EDIT: A further thought.  Since `na.approx` is only interpolating in columns, and your data is spacial, perhaps interpolating in rows would be useful too.  Then you could take the average.

`na.approx` fails when whole columns are `NA`, so we create a bigger dataset.

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(runif(64, 0, 100), nrow = 8)
missing_values <- sample(64, 15)
m[missing_values] <- NA
```

Run `na.approx` both ways.

```
by_col <- na.approx(m)
by_row <- t(na.approx(t(m)))
```

Find out the best guess.

```
default <- 50
best_guess <- ifelse(is.na(by_row), 
  ifelse(
    is.na(by_col), 
    default,              #neither known
    by_col                #only by_col known
  ), 
  ifelse(
    is.na(by_col), 
    by_row,               #only by_row known
    (by_row + by_col) / 2 #both known
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Richie. I'll try to guess values for the boundaries; as the spatial extension of my sst database is much bigger than the met model domain I will use I'm not specially worried about values on the boundaries. What I actually need is to fill the NA values in the central region of the data frame.

Comment: Whoever downvoted me, please can you leave a comment explaining what you didn't like.  If you don't provide feedback then I can't improve the answer.

Comment: -1 not true that you need start and end values.   End points can be extended as in Felix's answer or in `na.fill` .

Comment: Hi, in this case I don't think it is necessary but I can try and look for the results. Thanks, your answer was the right one for me.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck: Point taken; have clarified answer.

Answer (score 20):

`na.approx()` follows the `approx()` function in only interpolating values, not extrapolating them, by default. However, as described in the help page for `approx()`, you can specify `rule = 2` to extrapolate as a constant value of the nearest extreme. Following on from Richie Cotton's example:

```
na.approx(m, rule = 2)
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 26.55087 20.16819 62.911404 68.70228
[2,] 37.21239 35.47206  6.178627 38.41037
[3,] 64.01658 50.77592  6.178627 38.41037
[4,] 90.82078 66.07978  6.178627 38.41037
```

Equivalently, you can use "last observation carry forward" explicitly.

```
na.locf(na.approx(m))
## "first observation carry backwards" too:
na.locf(na.locf(na.approx(m)), fromLast = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works but maybe is not the good one for my data. As the data are sea surface temperature maybe it is not a good idea to extrapolate as constant value in case NA data is over sea (although most NA cases are over land points) where smooth transition between grid points is what you usually find.

Comment: `na.approx(... rule=2)` is gloriously undocumented on the manpage! It's buried in the 70-page PDF doc.

Comment: This answer with ```na.approx(..., rule = 2)``` saved my day!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to set `na.rm=TRUE`

> From the docs
>
> na.rm   logical. Should leading NAs be removed?

http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=zoo:na.approx

Comment: Hi Henrik. If I set na.rm=TRUE then I get a 3818x4096 data frame and I need to retain all 4096x4096 values.

Comment: Hmm, how about skipping the fancy interpolation and make a simple loop that when seeing a NA copies the last non-NA value?

Comment: I am new to R and will have to look for loop syntax, I am trying to manage with basic commands. How do I retain the last non-NA value? What happens if the first value in the column is NA? Also, I prefer a smooth transition between data values. These are sea surface temperature values and NAs are points over land where the met model needs "realistic" values to avoid numerical problems when solving the equations. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I understand your problem, but I guess it will not be very accurate land temperatures if you interpolate from SST. Maybe, take a look for inverse distance weighted interpolation and pretend your SST data is point measurments??

Comment: I'm not worried about the accuracy because the model knows where are land/sea points and it just needs a smooth transition. But I will look for inverse distance weighted interpolation. Thanks.

Comment: The link is broken.