# Linear interpolation between values in rows with n steps

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that measures values at a start, t1, t2, tx, and end. I would like to linearly interpolate between each time point in n number of steps.

For example, the dataframe I have is:

```
data <- data.frame(
  GroupVar = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  timepoint = c("Start", "t1", "End", "Start", "t1", "End"),
  Value = c(100, 50, 10, 100, 40, 15)
)
```

The data I would like to have is:

```
data2 <- data.frame(
  GroupVar = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  timepoint = c("Start", "t0.33", "t0.66", "t1", "t0.33", "t0.66", "End", "Start", "t0.33", "t0.66", "t1", "t0.33", "t0.66", "End"),
  Value = c(100, 83.3, 66.6, 50, 36.7, 23.4, 10, 100, 80, 60, 40, 31.7, 23.4, 15),
  isInterp = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
)
```

There is a varying number of observations between `Start` and `End` for `timepoint` between different `GroupVar`groups. The example has two steps between each measurement, but I would like this to be a parameter.

I've tried using `dplyr`'s `group_by` and `arrange` functions with no luck. I don't need the `timepoint` variable specifically to be `t0.33`, that's just to show it's equal timesteps.

Comment: Some similarities to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926984/using-approx-in-dplyr.   Is `t1` always halfway between Start and End? Do you always want `n=7`, with two steps added between each of the provided rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
fun <- function(tm, val, n = 2) {
  tmp <- Map(function(st, en) seq(st, en, length.out = n+2)[-c(1, n+2)],
             val[-length(val)], val[-1])
  tmp2 <- lapply(tmp, function(z) sprintf("t%0.03f", seq_along(z) / (n+1)))
  out <- Map(function(tm2, val2) data.frame(timepoint=tm2, Value=val2, isInterp=1),
             tmp2, tmp) |>
    c(list(data.frame(timepoint = tm, Value = val, isInterp=0))) |>
    do.call(rbind, args = _)
  ord <- if (val[1] > val[length(val)]) -1 else +1
  out[order(ord*out$Value),]
}
```

Demo:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(GroupVar) %>%
  reframe(fun(timepoint, Value))
# # A tibble: 14 × 4
#    GroupVar timepoint Value isInterp
#    <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 A        Start     100          0
#  2 A        t0.333     83.3        1
#  3 A        t0.667     66.7        1
#  4 A        t1         50          0
#  5 A        t0.333     36.7        1
#  6 A        t0.667     23.3        1
#  7 A        End        10          0
#  8 B        Start     100          0
#  9 B        t0.333     80          1
# 10 B        t0.667     60          1
# 11 B        t1         40          0
# 12 B        t0.333     31.7        1
# 13 B        t0.667     23.3        1
# 14 B        End        15          0
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `approx` and modulo

```
> intrp_TP <- \(x, f=2L) {
+   stopifnot(f > 0)
+   f <- as.integer(f)
+   n <- length(x$Value) + 2*f
+   a <- b <- array(, n)
+   a[seq_len(n) %% (f + 1) == 1] <- x$Value
+   a <- approx(a, xout=seq_along(a))$y
+   b[seq_len(n) %% (f + 1) == 1] <- x$timepoint
+   b[is.na(b)] <- 
+     sprintf('t%s', substr(seq.int(0, 1, len=f + 2), 1, 4))[-c(1, f + 2)]
+   data.frame(el(x$GroupVar), b, a) |> setNames(names(x))
+ }
```

We can put it  in `by`

```
> by(data, ~GroupVar, intrp_TP) |> c(make.row.names=FALSE) |> do.call(what='rbind')
   GroupVar timepoint     Value
1         A     Start 100.00000
2         A     t0.33  83.33333
3         A     t0.66  66.66667
4         A        t1  50.00000
5         A     t0.33  36.66667
6         A     t0.66  23.33333
7         A       End  10.00000
8         B     Start 100.00000
9         B     t0.33  80.00000
10        B     t0.66  60.00000
11        B        t1  40.00000
12        B     t0.33  31.66667
13        B     t0.66  23.33333
14        B       End  15.00000
```

`f=2` is default but be also can use `f=4` for instance.

```
> by(data, ~GroupVar, intrp_TP, f=4) |> c(make.row.names=FALSE) |> do.call(what='rbind')
   GroupVar timepoint Value
1         A     Start   100
2         A      t0.2    90
3         A      t0.4    80
4         A      t0.6    70
5         A      t0.8    60
6         A        t1    50
7         A      t0.2    42
8         A      t0.4    34
9         A      t0.6    26
10        A      t0.8    18
11        A       End    10
12        B     Start   100
13        B      t0.2    88
14        B      t0.4    76
15        B      t0.6    64
16        B      t0.8    52
17        B        t1    40
18        B      t0.2    35
19        B      t0.4    30
20        B      t0.6    25
21        B      t0.8    20
22        B       End    15
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(GroupVar = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), timepoint = c("Start", 
"t1", "End", "Start", "t1", "End"), Value = c(100, 50, 10, 100, 
40, 15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```