# FIll zeros with previous value +1

Tags: r, dplyr, transform, sequence, fill

I have a record grouped by users. At the variable "day" there are some 0s, which I would like to have replaced in order of sequence (= previous value +1).

```
data <- data.frame(user = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), day = c(170,0,172,34,35,0,0,38))

data
  user day
1    1 170
2    1   0
3    1 172
4    2  34
5    2  35
6    2   0
7    2   0
8    2  38
```

I want to have the following:

```
data_new
  user day
1    1 170
2    1 171
3    1 172
4    2  34
5    2  35
6    2  36
7    2  37
8    2  38
```

I've tried the following (really inefficient and doesn't work for all cases...):

```
data = group_by(data, user) %>%
+   mutate(lead_day = lead(day),
+          day_new = case_when(day == 0 ~ lead_day - 1,
+                              day > 0 ~ day))
> data
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   user [2]
   user   day lead_day day_new
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1   170        0     170
2     1     0      172     171
3     1   172       NA     172
4     2    34       35      34
5     2    35        0      35
6     2     0        0      -1
7     2     0       38      37
8     2    38       NA      38
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: In your example, there is always a number in sequence *after* the 0s. If this is reflective of your  real data, you could use `approx` to do linear interpolation, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7317607/903061).

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is it the best way to do so?


data$day[data$day == 0] <- NA

data = group_by(data, user) %>%
  mutate(day = na.approx(day))

Comment: In base for the same effect you could do : `within(data, day[day==0] <- approx(seq_along(day),replace(day,day==0 ,NA),xout=which(day==0))$y)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Reduce`

```
data$day <-Reduce(function(x,y) if(y==0) x+1 else y, data$day,accumulate = TRUE)   
data
#   user day
# 1    1 170
# 2    1 171
# 3    1 172
# 4    2  34
# 5    2  35
# 6    2  36
# 7    2  37
# 8    2  38
```

Or as you use `tidyverse` already :

```
data %>% mutate(day = accumulate(day,~if(.y==0) .x+1 else .y))
#   user day
# 1    1 170
# 2    1 171
# 3    1 172
# 4    2  34
# 5    2  35
# 6    2  36
# 7    2  37
# 8    2  38
```